# What level are spells from an oracle's mystery?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I'll phrase this as an example. If an Oracle of Battle wants to cast [Wall of Fire](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/wallOfFire.html#_wall-of-fire) (from his mystery), what is the DC for the spell? The spell is a level 4 sor/wiz spell but a level 5 druid spell. Since it's not an oracle (or cleric) spell, which is the level to count for DC for the oracle?

Answer (score 10):

It's entirely possible, and probable, and supported by [precedent](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9oyl), that each of the nine mystery spells corresponds to the spell level that you can cast as an oracle of that level, which would make *wall of fire* a 4th-level spell for an Oracle of Battle 8.